# Is it against best practice to run more than two Romex cables in a receptacle box?

Tags: electrical

Is it safe to add more that two Romex per pop-out to a 1 gang box?

[image: adding romex]

*The purpose is to add a receptacle 5' directly above this box for a wall mounted TV (to hide the wires).*

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to the built-in clamps in plastic boxes. I have no idea. But there *is* another possible problem: box capacity. There is a limit based on the volume (cubic inches) of how many wires, devices, etc. can go into any particular box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a different box anyway to have the required space for "box fill" - that one could be "not the blue plastic junk" or larger blue plastic (if you love the junk) that has more openings.

I'm *obviously biased* in favor of "larger and steel" and then you can use suitable clamps specified for 2 cables, or more holes in the box, as you prefer.

A [major maker of blue boxes](https://carlonsales.com/techinfo/faqs/FAQ-ZipBoxes.pdf) instructs that you can only use one cable per integral clamp. And following instructions is code. They might have made your box but that part of the text is blocked by wires in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine for AC power cables to be wired in a "tree" topology. You can have Tee or X or even 5-way branches anywhere you want.

However, the limiting factor is **box fill rules**, which require a certain number of cubic inches in a box given the number of **wires** in it.  I won't get into the box fill calculations too much, but you get a discount on grounds ("4 for the price of 1") and a receptacle or other device in a box has a count also.  So do cable clamps if they protrude into the box.